# I don't understand how a certain step has been reached.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I have found the $\gcd(408,126) = 6$. Now I am using Bézout's identity to find the coefficients.

a) $408 = 3 * 126 + 30$

b) $126 = 4 * 30 + 6$

Now

$6 =  126 – (4 ·30)$     (1)

$ =  126 – 4 ·(408 – 3 ·126)$     (2)

Now the next statement is where I am lost. I don't understand how $(1 + 12)$ was found.

$=  (– 4) ·408 + (1 + 12) ·126$     (3)

$=  (– 4) ·408 + 13 ·126$       (4)

I was able to reach step number 2 on my own, but that's when I got stuck. I searched for the solution on google. that's when I found step (3) and (4). Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: It’s just rewriting (2). Note that two minuses make a plus. Hint: 1-4(-3)

Comment: Not directly related to you question, but it would much less error prone to use the *extended Euclidean algorithm* to determine Bézout's coefficients.